# How to use style's trigger but override the behavior

Tags: wpf, triggers

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool, ElementName=Window1}" Value="false" x:Name="PosTrig">
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool, ElementName=Window1}" Value="true">
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Hello,
I've defined a style and some triggers in it. Now I want to use this style for many buttons and use those triggers in many buttons, but with different behaviour. Let's say one button will get red and another green for the same trigger. How can I do this?

Comment: u can check style inheritance in resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to consider is using Attached Properties to give your style flexibility.

Here's a simple example using your scenario above.

**ButtonProperties**

This attached property class has two properties TrueBrush and FalseBrush that can be used in your styles and triggers:

```
public static class ButtonProperties
{
    #region TrueBrush (Attached Property)
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrueBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "TrueBrush",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(ButtonProperties),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static Brush GetTrueBrush(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush)obj.GetValue(TrueBrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTrueBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TrueBrushProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region FalseBrush (Attached Property)
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "FalseBrush",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(ButtonProperties),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static Brush GetFalseBrush(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush)obj.GetValue(FalseBrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFalseBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FalseBrushProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**XAML**

The implicit style sets default values for `TrueBrush` and `FalseBrush`. And you can easily override the colors on a separate button by setting the `TrueBrush` and `FalseBrush` attached properties directly on the button or you could create a separate explicit style (one with a key) based on your implicit style that has different values set for `TrueBrush` and `FalseBrush`.

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="local:ButtonProperties.TrueBrush" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="local:ButtonProperties.FalseBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding DataContext.MyBool, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.TrueBrush), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding DataContext.MyBool, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                    Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.FalseBrush), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton
                Height="20"
                Content="MyBool"
                IsChecked="{Binding MyBool, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Button
                Height="20"
                Margin="0,16,0,0"
                Content="Default Colors" />
            <Button
                Height="20"
                Margin="0,16,0,0"
                local:ButtonProperties.FalseBrush="Purple"
                local:ButtonProperties.TrueBrush="LightBlue"
                Content="Override Colors" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope this helps give you some ideas.